# Hooking up Dell printer 2155 CN to OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, printing, driver

I just got a new MacBook Air and called Dell about hooking up my printer. They told me that they have no drivers for OS X 10.9, which means I cannot use my Dell printers with my mac? I have a Dell 2155 CN printer. Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Did you try the 10.8 driver?

Comment: no, do you think that will work??

Comment: It's worth a try

Answer (score -1):

The Dell support told me today the Driver for Mac OS 10.8 doesn't support Mac OS beyhond the 10.8 version... so, I guess you can not use your printer until they upgrade the driver :-(

Comment: Hello again ! Finally I could install and use the driver with my Mac Book Air with Mac OS 10.8.2. It works pefectly well but instead of launching the normal installation, I choosed to customize it without installing the fax driver. And it works ! Good luck !